# ZF2 optionally change user password in form

Tags: zend-framework2

i want to have a form, where a logged in user can change his user data. Optionally he can insert a new password. I tried to remove the inputfilter of the 'password' and 'passwordVerification' fields, if the posted password is empty, but i don't know how to handle the save in my service, that the password gets not overwritten...

**Controller action**

```
public function indexAction() {
    $identity = $this->authentication()->getIdentity();
    $userService = $this->userService;

    $form = $this->userForm;
    $form->bind($identity);

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($form->get('password')->getValue() == '') {
            $validationGroup = $form->getValidationGroup();
            $passwordKey = array_search('password', $validationGroup);
            $passwordVerificationKey = array_search('passwordVerification', $validationGroup);

            unset($validationGroup[$passwordKey]);
            unset($validationGroup[$passwordVerificationKey]);

            $form->setValidationGroup($validationGroup);
            $form->getInputFilter()->remove('password');
            $form->getInputFilter()->remove('passwordVerification');
        }

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $userService->saveUser($form->getData());

            $this->flashMessenger()->addSuccessMessage('Data has been saved successfully');
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('admin/account');
        }
    }

    return array(
        'userForm' => $form
    );
}
```

**User service**

```
public function saveUser(User $user) {
    if ($password = $user->getPassword()) {
        $user->setPassword($this->authenticationService->getAdapter()->getBcrypt()->create($password));
    }

    $this->userRepository->save($user);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

when i'm doing this i use a use an unmapped password property (e.g. passwordForm) in my user entity which is used in the form so the original password is not overridden. if the passwordForm field is filled you can override the original password with that value